# ASP.NET MVC2 - Trim white space from form submits before server-side validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, attributes, validation, trim

If I add a validation attribute:

```
public class ProductDownloadListModel
{        
    //xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx
    [Required]
    [StringLength(17)]
    public string PSN { get; set; }
    public DateTime PsnExpirationDate { get; set; } 
    public DataTable Downloads { get; set; } 

}
```

and the user enters a 17-character string but includes white space on the end, I get a validation error because the string is greater than that specified by the `[StringLength(17)]` attribute. How can I prevent this? I'd prefer not to have to have javaScript trim the string before submits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do a trim on your set for the PSN.

```
public string PSN
{
    get
    {
        return (this.psn == null) ? string.Empty : this.psn;
    }
    set
    {
        this.psn = (value == null || value.Trim().Length == 0) ? null :value.Trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well that was frickin obvious. =/

Comment: Yeah, well, I can't even tell you how many times I have beat my head against the wall over something obvious.  Part of the job apparently. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the maxlength attribute on the html input?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp

Comment: The problem is that the users typically copy & paste the serial number from another document, and sometimes pick up spaces before or after the relevant string. I think that pasting too much text into a field with the maxlength property set just trims the excess characters, which would hurt their little heads.